# Docker Image errors

Tags: docker

I pulled the Postgres image from docker hub but when I run it gives me the following error:

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G28Bs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message!

Something like this will work:
`docker run postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`

Also see the postgres image on Docker for more help: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres